# Ruling on masturbation in this case

Tags: masturbation

I know that in Islam it is haram to masturbate, even in case a man cannot marry and in case one cannot marry than he has to resort into fasting, for it diminishes sexual desire. But what if the man in question has huge sexual desire, cannot marry in any way whatsoever and he has DIABETES (he cannot fast because of that)???

Strain: Sunni

Creed: Athari

Manhaj: Salafi

Madhab/jurisprudence followed: generally none , although I'd personally  deem the Hanbali one as the best because it was the madhab of Imam al Bukhari, Ibn Taymiyyah and Muhammad ibn Abd al Wahhab.

P.S: I'm not justifying masturbation forcibly in this case, but I want to know whether the "daroorat" issue applies here

P.P.S advice to those who engage in it. From my experience, I can tell you that, when I was being accustomed to masturbate thrice a day, it rendered me just numb mentally and psychologically, not making me focus on things properly and moreover it made me forget thinks very quickly and often. It harms more mentally than physically, even though there's a great extent in both aspects. Don't masturbate.
Even zina, which is a bigger fa7sha, is physically healthier than masturbation because it can be just anatomically and physically similar to sex between married man and his wife (NOTE: I'm NOT condoning zina in any way shape or form, you'll get what I mean if you're mind bearing) (the physical outcome from sexual intercourse between two healthy people of opposite gender and the marriage counterpart of the latter would be the same)

Comment: The verdict for masturbation  doesn't change just because of the madhhab or circumstances. The majority considers it haram. Ibn Tayymiyah considers it haram or makroh as it is much better than committing zina. You may find a helpful response in [Is masturbation permissible for a man during an extended period of unmarried life?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/is-masturbation-permissible-for-a-man-during-an-extended-period-of-unmarried-lif).  None of the named scholars would consider himself hanbali. as all of them had an own madhhab which differs from the hanbali school of fiqh.

Comment: I mentioned another condition which makes the scenario more peculiar, the person involved cannot fast because he is diabetic.

Comment: Yes but many Muslims fast even if having diabetes or heart issues. And if you masturbate you usually do it in secret and as long as it doesn't become a habit one can repent from it why should we pretend that we are free from sins? Allah created as and He knows we are sinners and He expects from us to repent. As long as there is difference of opinion on a matter there are halal options (like sports) and repentance is the most important sign of faith!

Comment: As far as I know diabetic people aren't able to fast (I didn't mean it is forbidden for them while using "cannot", but that they aren't able to).

Comment: They are able to fast, but they harm their lives and no good physician would recommend them to do so, but most Muslim physicians are afraid to hinder people from fasting this is why I've asked [How to determine when one shouldn't fast due to sickness?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49845/how-to-determine-when-one-shouldnt-fast-due-to-sickness). AFAIK it is essential for diabetic people to have a (at least a small) meal each x-hours, but many Muslims think fasting is more important.

Comment: No, they were all followers of imam Ahmad as far as I know, especially Muhammad ibn abd al Wahhab, since he has laid down the religious foundations of the nowadays Saudi Arabia, which not coincidentally follows heavily the Hanbali fiqh, even though they give huge respect to Imam Malik too.

Comment: Only ibn Tayymiyah and ibn Abdalwahhab started their career as hanbalis some hanbalis consider ibn Tayymiyah from among them however he considers himself a mujtahid. As for al-Bukhari he never followed any madhhab and had clearly his own opinions. Many early scholars even didn't consider ibn Hanbal a fiqh scholar. The osol of his madhhab were compiled more than a century after his death.

Comment: You are never allowed to masturbate. The only time you _might_ be allowed is you had a serious physical situation and the doctor needed a sample. Otherwise you generally don’t commit one sin to avoid another.You can't commit to a sin upon stress. Whatever you do in life you'll have some form of mental stress. We're instructed to ask Allah to help. Otherwise the poor would come and say I need to steal otherwise I'll die. Yet Allah has left plenty of ways and will aid believers. For more see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36703/how-can-i-stop-masturbating/37278#37278)

Comment: Well there are cases that are very, very discussible because they are peculiar to an extent that you can never imagine (not trying to justify sin, big no). There's a huge difference between the times of the Prophets and our times, and despite the technological advancement and its derived comforts, there are plenty of situations who happen to be extremely difficul both to overcome and to judge, but that's another topic in and of itself. Anyway thanks for your contribution

Comment: @abdul what he made halal is to remain halal and what he has made haram is to remain haram. There are many narrations that say such. Otherwise if we are to change and conform then we have change our religion to the desire and need of everyone. Look at the west and see how Christianity has conformed itself to people

Comment: @Honey you didn't get what I was trying to say, I didn't mean to change the religion for our desires, don't be so narrow-minded (no, I'm not pushing liberalism, I'm Salafi as far as I hold myself), what I'm saying is that generally haram things (hukm 3am) can, only in certain scenarios, be permitted. If you are in a desert and you have only pork available, is it haram for you to eat for not starving? Yes, and I was asking LIKEWISE for this case.

Comment: There may be total narration stating it is haram, and without them this is considered haram by default, but with or without the narrations about a general haram thing, this doesn't deny that there may be a case in which that haram thing is permitted just for necessity

Comment: On this site, we don’t accuse others of being narrow minded. We only discuss (not debate). The similitude you made is not reasonable. In the desert he has no other solution. He’ll literally die. Eating pork has very little problem vs dying. But for abstaining yourself from sex, you have countless solutions. Many others have done such and succeeded. If people who didn’t have sex all went crazy, then what you’ve said would be right. Masturbation, has its own problems. The soul and mind would slowly take a toll. If person cannot fast, while seeking Allah’s aid he can eat less and do exercise

Comment: Ok, then you should've said "this is haram in any case because there are countless solutions" or "there are not peculiar cases allowing masturbation", not a blunt " masturbation is haram" or "it is haram anyway", because the latter can be understood as a general ruling, not as a ruling encompassing peculiar cases. We do not have the same understanding of things, and that's normal.

Comment: No, I didn't say you're narrow minded, I said don't be closed minded in this issue I'm talking about and trying to understand openly what I'm meaning by not saying "it is haram and haram only" by mentioning general rulings only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is masturbation permissible for a man during an extended period of unmarried life?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/is-masturbation-permissible-for-a-man-during-an-extended-period-of-unmarried-lif)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Majority of the scholars view it as haram and some view it as permissible due to them feeling there isn’t no concrete evidence while others see it as permissible under some conditions like fearing committing zina and being unable to marry so depending on what you believe is right then you can or cannot. You can do dhikr if you are in doubt about which to believe is right.

Answer (score 0):

Surah Al-Mu'minun verse 7 makes it explicitly clear that the action is haraam. Darurah doesn't apply here. Darurah is defined as the person will be harmed if he does not take the haraam option. Is there a threat to your life if you don't perform the action?

> And those who guard their chastity.   Except from their wives or (the
> slaves) that their right hands possess, - for then, they are free from
> blame. But whoever seeks **beyond** that, then those are the
> transgressors.

Zina (adultery, fornication) does not refer only to penetration, rather there is the zina of the hand, which is touching that which is forbidden, and the zina of the eyes, which is looking at that which is forbidden, even though zina that is committed with the private parts, is the zina which is punishable with the hadd punishment.

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying. Allah fixed the
> very portion of adultery which a man will indulge in. There would be
> no escape from it. The adultery of the eye is the lustful look and the
> adultery of the ears is listening to voluptuous (song or talk) and the
> adultery of the tongue is licentious speech and the **adultery of the
> hand** is the lustful grip (embrace) and the adultery of the feet is to
> walk (to the place) where he intends to commit adultery and the heart
> yearns and desires which he may or may not put into effect. Narrated
> by al-Bukhaari, 5889; Muslim, 2657.

> “And **come not near** to unlawful sex. Verily, it is a Faahishah (i.e.
> anything that transgresses its limits: a great sin, and an evil way
> that leads one to hell unless Allaah Forgives him)”
>
> [al-Isra’ 17:32]